# Как реализовать остановку бесконечного цикла функции в телеграм боте на питоне?

Tags: python, telebot

Я сделал бота который по текстовому запросу пользователя делает поиск в твиттере и только что опубликованные посты отправляет в телеграм бота. Очевидно для такого парсинга у меня используется бесконечный цикл. Я решил закинуть свою программу на сервер, чтобы каждый мог пользоваться этим ботом в телеграме. Столкнулся с проблемой что не знаю как остановить бота внутри самого телеграма, потому что при определенных запросах он сильно спамит.

Условный пример программы:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hello_bro(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ' + message.from_user.username + "!, напиши пару ключевых слов для поиска твитов.")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def search(message):
    здесь фрагмент кода на селениуме
    tweet = 'новый найденный твит'
    while True:
        bot.send_message(uid,
                        f'User: {tweet[0]}\n Handle: {tweet[1]} \n PostDate: {tweet[2]} \n\n TweetText:\n {tweet[3]} \n')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
def stop_command(message):
  print("Бот остановлен")
  

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Столкнулся с точно такой же проблемой. Поделись: как решил?

Answer (score -1):

Тебе бы сделать отдельную функцию, что-то вроде

```
def check():
                переменные_которые необходимы для проверки, например что статья найдена
                if not (условие переменной):
                    return True
```

и после return True продолжаешь свой цикл, должно помочь, у меня подобная ситуация и она работает. По итогу должно быть так, но уже в теле цикла:

```
bot.send_message(uid,
                        f'User: {tweet[0]}\n Handle: {tweet[1]} \n PostDate: {tweet[2]} \n\n TweetText:\n {tweet[3]} \n')
if check(): break
```

для наглядности мой тебе код, там по факту только свои значения необходимые подставлять и все

```
import win32api
import time
import pyautogui

while True:
    l = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
    r = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)
    print(l)
    if l < 0 and r < 0:
        for i in range(1):
            def check():
                global l, r
                l = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
                r = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

                print(l)
                if not (l < 0 and r < 0):
                    return True


            pyautogui.moveRel(0, 50)
            if check(): break
            time.sleep(0.06)
            pyautogui.moveRel(0, 50)
            if check(): break
            time.sleep(0.06)
            pyautogui.moveRel(0, 50)
            if check(): break
            time.sleep(0.06)
            pyautogui.moveRel(0, 50)
            if check(): break
            time.sleep(0.06)
            pyautogui.moveRel(0, 10)
            if check(): break
            time.sleep(0.06)
            pyautogui.moveRel(0, 10)
            if check(): break
            time.sleep(0.06)
            pyautogui.moveRel(0, 1)
```

Comment: все равно не понял как решить проблему. Мне нужно чтобы цикл работал до тех пор, пока пользователь не пропишет /stop в самом боте к примеру